# Cannot submit two dimension `List` from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, asp.net-mvc-5

Class `CreateActivityViewModel`will be passed to View.

```
 public class CreateActivityViewModel
{
 public List<List<int>> SelectedDepartmentIds { get; set; }
 ...
}
```

In the View, using these code to generate html code:

```
<div class="form-group">

    @Html.Label("报名范围", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "col-xs-12"})
    <div>
        <button id="repeat" type="button">增加单位范围</button>
    </div>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.MaxDepartmentLevel; i++)
    {
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            @if (i == 0)
            {
                @Html.Label((i + 1) + "级单位", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDepartmentIds[0][i], Model.Departments,
                    "请选择单位", new {@class = "form-control department"})
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Label((1 + i) + "级单位", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDepartmentIds[0][i], Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
                    "所有单位", new {@class = "form-control department"})
            }
        </div>
    }


</div>
```

Here `x => x.SelectedDepartmentIds[0][i]` is the two dimention `List` that cannot be passed back to server. When debuging, `createActivityViewModel.SelectedDepartmentIds=null`. However, Using Chrome Dev Tools to see what is passing to server, I saw `SelectedDepartmentIds` do submit:

[image]

In fact, I have tried almost the same work in other place, the only difference I think is that the success work is passing one dimension `List` and now two dimension. Does ASP.NET not support binding two dimension List or what?

Comment: Could you show your `Create` action method signature? Also can you show us the `Content-Type` request header?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thanks! Inspired, I checked `Create`action signature and found I forgot add that property in `[Bind(Include =...)]`.

Comment: Your using a view model so you should never have a `[Bind]` attribute

Answer (score 1):

This should work as expected. From the comments it seems that you have forgotten to include the property to the `[Bind(Include=...)]` attribute that your Create action is using. This being said, since you are using a view model you don't need any Bind attributes. The properties that are part of the view model will simply be bound. It is much less error prone and explicit.